# Kohana v3 application execution time

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

Hi I am using the Kohana v3 profiler and I notice the application execution time at the bottom. I don't really know what this is.

Is this how long it takes kohana to run through controller and php code or is it the total time it took my webpage to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this how long it takes kohana to
>   run through controller and php code or
>   is it the total time it took my
>   webpage to load?

It is profiling feature that tells you ***total time your php code/page took to render on the browser***.

**More Info:**

- http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Kohana_Profiler